# jQuery map up array with exisiting table

Tags: jquery, arrays, dictionary, asynchronous

In the ready DOM i have an existing table consisting of a number of rows.

Asynchronously I then get a json list of elements.

Now, the amount of elements in the json array will always equal the amount of rows in the table.

Further, the first element in the json array will always "belong" to the first row in the table, the second element to the second row and so on.

So basically having a table with 3 rows, would mean I would get a json list:

```
$.each(list,function(k,v){
    console.log(v.item);
});
```

that in turn would return three item values:

`foo`
`bar`
`baz`

What I need is (sticking with the example above) that "foo" get appended to the first tr (append a td), "bar" to the second, and "baz" to the third.

So a table looking like this:

[image: Static table]

Would look like this afterwards:

[image: Table manipulated]

Any pointers is much appreciated, have a feeling I've gone blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright let's solve this step by step. Use the appropriate table selector.

```
var $rows = $('#myTableId tr'); //store list of rows in a variable

$.each(list,function(index,val){ //for each value in the list
    $rows.eq(index).append('<td>'+val+'</td>') 
    //get each row by index. 
    //This works naturally since first item goes into first row, and etc.
    //append a td element with the content inside.
})
```